How do Ryanair transfers work at destination?
I bought a ticket with Ryanair and booked the transfer from the airport to destination. I was expecting to get further instructions, but at the moment, a few hours before the flight, I didn't receive any info. How do these transfers work? Does anyone have experience?

The usual way this works (for private transfers) is that your driver will be waiting for you at arrivals (right after baggage claim) with a sign (whiteboard, paper or tablet) with your name.

Ryanair is a point-to-point low cost carrier, and does not provide post-flight transfers. Still, at least one Ryanair web page links to other providers' private transfers. With whom or what entity did you book the transfer?

If it is a small airport well away from the city expect a bus/coach, which may have a regular departure spot outside the terminal building.

@DavidRecallsMonica Ryanair does not provide transfers, but you can book a transfer or rent a car via their web, together with booking a flight ticket.

@DavidRecallsMonica Ryanair doesn't operate the transfer but sells the service, as an extra, as part of the booking process. No all airports have such service available.

My experience:
When I got to the destination airport, outside, there was a man waiting with a sign saying, "Ryanair transfers". I checked with him, he had my name and from there everything was normal. He then routed me to the van doing my transfer.
Additional info: these are group transfers. We only left once the whole group assigned to the van arrived. I saw some vans depart earlier.
Note: The transfer went quite badly, both for the time I waited and the fact that I was left at the wrong destination. But that's the fault of the operator and I will address it in the proper place.

Thank you for sharing your experience! When I saw your question back then I had to admit I wondered whether the transfers were private or shared (not much info on the topic on the Ryanair site). I suppose from your answer that they are shared?

Yes @jcaron they are in did.
